# Center button horizontally with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS and I am having difficulty centering a button within a `<div>`.  Here is the code I currently have:

```css
.box-information {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  padding: 0 10px 60px 10px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

.button-blue:link,
.button-blue:visited {
  width: 7em;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: rgba(66, 85, 123, 1);
  font-size: 1.0em;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-information your-business">
  <p class="title-information">
    Your Business
  </p>
  <p class="text-information">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <a class="button-blue learn-more" href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

I am able to offset the button from the bottom, and I can offset the button horizontally if I use anything but AUTO.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```css
.box-information {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  padding: 0 10px 60px 10px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

.button-blue:link,
.button-blue:visited {
  width: 7em;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: rgba(66, 85, 123, 1);
  font-size: 1.0em;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-information your-business">
  <p class="title-information">
    Your Business
  </p>
  <p class="text-information">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
  <a class="button-blue learn-more" href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Guys,  I apologize, but I omitted some information.  I was able to center the button with margin: 0 auto;.  However, I want to pin the button to the bottom of the box (i.e. bottom: 10px).  I have three boxes next to each other, each box has a different amount of text, and I want the boxes to be the same height and the button to be spaced consistently off the bottom of each box.

Comment: Ha, so it that case you can position it with position:absolute, left: 50%, margin-right: half-of the width of the button.

Comment: I may not fully understand your suggestion.  When I use left: % then I can get the button to move horizontally, however, it won't stay centered as the browser's width changes.  I changed the width of the button to 120px and used margin-right: 60px; and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: HI Guys, Felix's solution worked.    left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); seems to be what I was looking for.  Now I need to understand the transform command.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To center a block element in it's parent, all you need to do is add:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

to the button's CSS properties.

(You will need to remove the `position: absolute` and the absolute positioning properties first.)

Take a look at this `codepen`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXYEpd

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-left:50%;`. This set my button to the middle of its parent control.

Comment: This is close but it doesn't take into account the width of the button itself, resulting in the left edge of the button being positioned at 50% not the center of the button being at 50%. I wish there was a way to use `calc()` to subtract 50% of the width of the button from the 50% `margin-left` value, but alas I don't believe this capability exists without using a constant value to set the width of the button and then use half of this value to subtract from the `margin-left: 50%`